# Trying to install in Windows 7 - Fails with CRC error

Tags: node.js

When trying to install in Windows 7, I repeatedly get the following error :-

"Failed to correctly acquire installer_nodejs_windows.msi file: CRC error" whilst in the "Downloading prerequisite software" stage.

Any clues?

Comment: Try to remove your installer and download it again. It looks like your installer is corrupted.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Andrew, but I tried that with exactly the same result - maybe the file on the server is corrupt?